# Error: can't parse PCC subspaces from PCCT

Tags: boot

My computer seems a bit slow when it boots, and this error seems to be the cause, and it occurs on every startup. Otherwise I don't see much of a problem (though, again, I'm new to this and don't know if I would notice if it's not running exactly right)

I've googled this and read through some of the posts here, and I'm finding a few differences between what my case is and others. I'm new to linux, so please bear with me.

Upon installation, I wiped Win10 from my computer (Lenovo T440p, graphics card is an Nvidia GeForce GT730M), so there shouldn't be any dual booting option or error related to windows. I'm not booting from a flash drive(or any external drive), and so I'm not sure about where my problem is.